# How to match both UDP and TCP for given ports in one line with nftables

Tags: linux, configuration, firewall, netfilter, nftables

How can i do this in a single line?

```
tcp dport 53 counter accept comment "accept DNS"
udp dport 53 counter accept comment "accept DNS"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**With a recent enough `nftables`, you can just write:**

```
meta l4proto {tcp, udp} th dport 53 counter accept comment "accept DNS"
```

---

Actually, you can do even better:

```
set okports {
  type inet_proto . inet_service
  counter
  elements = {
    tcp . 22,  # SSH
    tcp . 53,  # DNS (TCP)
    udp . 53   # DNS (UDP)
}
```

And then:

```
meta l4proto . th dport @okports accept
```

<sub>You can also write `domain` instead of `53` if you prefer using port/service names (from `/etc/services`).</sub>

Comment: Hello. What does "th" mean in this context?

Comment: @Lethargos `th` means "Transport Header". `th dport` is a "human readable" shortcut for `@th,16,16` which means: read 16 bits at offset 16 in the transport header. This is where the destination port is set when either TCP or UDP is used. See [this documentation](https://www.mankier.com/8/nft#Payload_Expressions-Raw_Payload_Expression) for further details.

Comment: So it works for both tcp and udp simply because the dport starts for both at 16th bit?

Comment: @Lethargos exactly! :) That's why you shouldn't use it with other protocols (as the documentation warns), hence the check to be sure that the ̀l4proto` is either TCP or UDP but not something else.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of telling it's possible (but probably not that useful), yes it's possible, using a [recent enough nftables](https://lwn.net/Articles/748564/) and a raw payload expression.

So for the `inet` (dual `ip`/`ip6`) table, you have to first filter the right level 4 protocol (here TCP=6 and UDP=17) using a set, then filter the port 53. That's handy, [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) and [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Service_ports) have the same location for the destination port in their respective format. `dport` is expressed as the offset of the destination port in the TCP/UDP part of the packet: 16 bits, with a size of 16 bits as seen in the previous links. While `tcp` and `udp` can be used by their symbolic name, It appears that `dns` must be stated as `53` not `dns`, I can only imagine that's because `dns/tcp` and `dns/udp` (or `domain` see later) are in two different "protocol namespaces".

The resulting command is (additional single quotes or else escaping the double quotes is needed here):

```
# nft 'add rule inet filter input meta l4proto {tcp, udp} @th,16,16 53 counter accept comment "accept DNS"'
```

If you want it for IPv4 only, initialize the corresponding `ip` table and chains and replace `inet` with `ip`.

Please also note that almost the same is given as example in the [0.8.3 release notes](https://lwn.net/Articles/748564/) and is now included in [`nft`'s man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch-backports/nftables/nft.8.en.html#RAW_PAYLOAD_EXPRESSION), alas, that example doesn't work: `dns` and `http` have to be replaced with `53` and `80` (and anyway some distributions/versions might have required `domain` instead of `dns`).

Comment: Is there any performance difference between the two original simple rules compared to this single complex rule?

Comment: @scai probably not (ok it should be a little better). It's all compiled into bytecode in the end. Try `nft --debug=netlink -a list ruleset`

Comment: Why do you think such a rule is not that useful? I think it's more elegant to place both tcp and udp in one rule then having a rule for each - such as in the case with dns where you actually do need to use both, and nowadays http with quic.

Comment: Btw, since a few months or years, `th` got a bit more official in this case. The command I wrote in 2018 would automatically have `@th,16,16 53` decoded back as `th dport 53` which is now a valid syntax. I'll have to revisit the answer.

Comment: @Lethargos And it's certainly useful, but when I wrote the answer I felt it wasn't worth the trouble of needing a raw payload expression (which was brand new then).

Comment: ... and I didn't see there is already a new answer with the new syntax as accepted answer. nothing to revisit.